# syntax error for mysql declaration of variable

Tags: mysql, syntax

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat(IN p1 INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE x INT DEFAULT 0;
  REPEAT SET x = x + 1; UNTIL x > p1 END REPEAT;
END
```

I get an syntax error:

> `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for > the right syntax to use near '' at line 3`

But for me, everything seems to be correct. i really don't have any clue! can anybody help?

thanks

Comment: You should accept the answer, because it's correct.

Answer (score 64):

You need to temporarily [change the delimiter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html) so the MySQL client doesn't think you're done with your statement when it sees the semicolon on line 3:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat(IN p1 INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE x INT DEFAULT 0;
  REPEAT SET x = x + 1; UNTIL x > p1 END REPEAT;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: this should be marked as answer, thanks John Flatness

Answer (score -4):

Remove the DECLARE, you should be able to just do this:

```
SET @x = 0;
```

Also, variables need to be prefixed with the @ symbol

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but this really helped me.

Comment: This will create variables that are visible to the whole session, you just want to declare them as then they are visible only inside the stored procedure.

Comment: Agree with Skiwi.. this is a real bad answer.